# ODBC PHP .dbf querying Add column values

Tags: php, odbc, dbf, dbase

Im using ODBC dBase PHP, and I just want to add column values together. Usually in mysql this works `SELECT (SUM(RMTRAN) + SUM(EXTRAN)) - (SUM(RMTRANDIS) + SUM(EXTRANDIS)) AS receivable, CODE FROM HISTORY WHERE DATE = X GROUP BY CODE ORDER BY CODE`

how do i do that for ODBC dbf? NOTE EXTRAN is possibly null

Is there a website for how to query dbfs?

Answer (score 0):

The query should work on a DBF file, but note, that DBF file of dBase type (unlike of VFP type) doesn't support NULL values. To replace possible NULL values with 0 (for instance), use the NVL() function:

```
SELECT (SUM(RMTRAN) + SUM(NVL(EXTRAN,0))) - (SUM(RMTRANDIS) + SUM(EXTRANDIS)) AS receivable ...
```

Also [this topic](http://dbf-software.com/sql-select.html) may be useful for you.